# Sliding GroupBoxes

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl

Windows 10. Delphi 11. VCL.

This seems to me a standard Windows behaviour, but I am stumped how to do it.

I have two GroupBoxes next to each other on a Form.

I want to be able to hover the mouse over the border between the two, get that special mouse pointer, and then be able to drag the border left and right, with obviousely one GroupBox getting smaller and the other larger.

If this is not possible with GroupBoxes, what else can I use?

Comment: No, this is very much not standard Win32 behaviour. But you can always drop a `TSplitter` on your form. Let the first group box be `Align = alLeft` and the other `alClient`. The splitter is `alLeft`.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that this TSplitter existed. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: If this seems standard to you then please name a few programs where you experienced this before.

Comment: Yes, I nitpick that, because you clearly size panes or panels, not boxes. If using the term "box" I imply a frame around them, like bevels, optionally having a caption. "Explorer" alone means nothing - you also imply having the folder TreeView and the file ListView (whereas an Explorer alone can also be just the folder content).

Comment: @AmigoJack If we are nitpicky you can use `TSplitter` for resizing of basically any visual component like Panel, GroupBoxe, Button, Labels, Toolbar and so on.  Any visual component that supports alignment can be resized using `TSplitter`

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, every. No, that's still neither "_standard Windows behaviour_", nor should those be everywhere. Put Splitters near buttons, labels and checkboxes and the accessibility of your windows is a disaster for handicapped users. Not even sizable dialog windows are a _standard_ in Windows (especially message boxes).

Comment: Okay guys, please stop.